# Interpreting binary files as ASCII

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a binary file (which I've created in C) and I would like to have a look inside the file. Obviously, I won't be able to "see" anything useful as it's in binary. However I do know that contains certain number of rows with numbers in double precision. I am looking for a script to just read some values and print them so I can verify the if they are in the right range. In other words, it would be like doing `head` or `tail` in linux on an text file.
Is there a way of doing it?
Right now I've got something in Python, but it does not do what I want:

```
CHUNKSIZE = 8192
file = open('eigenvalues.bin', 'rb')
data = list(file.read())
print data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`array` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) to read homogenous binary-representation numbers:

```
from array import array

data = array('d')
CHUNKSIZE = 8192
rowcount = CHUNKSIZE / data.itemsize  # number of doubles we find in CHUNKSIZE bytes

with open('eigenvalues.bin', 'rb') as eg:
    data.fromfile(eg, rowcount)
```

The `array.array` type otherwise behaves just like a list, only the type of values it can hold is constricted (in this case to `float`).

Depending on the input data, you may need to add a `data.byteswap()` call after reading to switch between little and big-endian. Use [`sys.byteorder`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.byteorder) to see what byteorder was used to read the data. If your data was written on a platform using little-endianess, swap if your platform uses the other form, and vice-versa:

```
import sys

if sys.byteorder == 'big':
    # data was written in little-endian form, so swap the bytes to match
    data.byteswap()
```

Comment: @Seidr: `array` is a nice complimentary module to `struct`, if you are dealing with a sequence of just one type of C-standard binary data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use struct.unpack to convert binary data into a specific data type.

For example, if you want to read the first double from the binary data. (not tested, but believe this is correct)

```
struct.unpack("d",inputData[0:7])
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Answer (score 3):

You can see each byte of your file represented in unsigned decimal with this shell command:

```
od -t u1 eigenvalues.bin | less
```

Should you want to see a particular area and decode floating point numbers, you can use `dd` to extract them and `od -F` option to decode them, eg:

```
dd status=noxfer if=eigenvalues.bin bs=1 skip=800 count=16 | od -F
```

will show two double precision numbers stored at offset 800 and 808 in the binary file.

Note that according to the Linux tag set to your question, I assume you are using Gnu versions of `dd` and `od`.